# Caption below image and beside Content of page

Tags: captions

I want create Daily Page:

- Left: image & caption
- Center: "Daily Planner" text

But I can not put image and text parallel and caption not under image

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[format=plain,
            labelfont={bf,it},
            textfont=it]{caption}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent

\begin{figure}[!ht]

\put(\dimexpr\textwidth-18cm,0cm) [Nick name ABC]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{Image/kid_01.png}}


\end{figure}

\Huge Daily Planner

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A figure is a float, meaning it floats. It might well be that `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}` is not the ideal document class for your task. Could you perhaps describe a bit more clearly what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks @marmot. i want to create prinable calendar pdf: 365 page a day

Comment: I would recommend to do a google search with `site:tex.stackexchange.com calendar` in it, perhaps a picture search. I know that Ti*k*Z provides means to typeset calendars, but I would be really surprised if there were no alternatives.

Comment: Thanks. I know this calendar and searched. My above code will add this calendar. Can you recommend one solution for my above code? Thanks

Comment: @BVOT If you have a new question, please ask a new question and don't overwrite your previous one, to which you already got an answer.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use the *tcolorbox*  package and the starred version of *\captionof* macro
 from the *caption* package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,draft]{book}
  \usepackage[format=plain,
            labelfont={bf,it},
            textfont=it]{caption}

  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{tcolorbox}
  \usepackage{varwidth}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}

  \begin{document}

  \newcommand{\mybox}[4]%[\textwidth-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}-2mm]
  {%
    %\begin{figure}[!h]  % we don't need figure environment
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[line width=.5mm,
        rounded corners,
        draw= #2,
        inner ysep=10pt,
        text width= #1,
        outer sep=0]
        (one) {\vspace*{15pt}\\ \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth} #4 \end{varwidth}};

      \node[text=white,
      anchor=north east,
      align=center,
      minimum height=20pt] (two) at (one.north east) {#3 \hspace*{.5mm}};

      \path[fill=#2] (one.north west|-two.west) -- ($(two.west)+(-1.5cm,0pt)$) to[out=0,in=180] (two.south west) -- (two.south east) [rounded corners] -- (one.north east) -- (one.north west) [sharp corners] -- cycle;

      \node[text=white,
      anchor=north east,
      align=center,
      minimum height=20pt,
      text height=2ex] (three) at (one.north east) {ABC \hspace*{.5mm}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % \end{figure}
  }



\tcbset{sidebyside,
  size=minimal,
  colback=white,
  lower separated=false,
  halign upper=flush center,
  halign lower=flush left,
  lefthand width=4cm,
  frame empty,
}



\begin{tcolorbox}
  \includegraphics[width=4cm]{Image/kid_01.png}
\captionof*{figure}{Nick name ABC}

  \tcblower
 \Huge Daily Planner

\end{tcolorbox}

\vspace{2cm}


 \begin{tcolorbox}
  \includegraphics[width=4cm]{Image/kid_01.png}

  \tcblower
  %\Huge Daily Planner
   \mybox{5cm}{green!30!black}{ABC}{abc def glm } % note the curly braces around 5cm

\end{tcolorbox} 




\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please help with my new above error, thank Hafid

Comment: Hi Hafid, thanks for your help. I updated my code. And may be you can help about (3 box side by side). Thanks

Comment: Hi @BVOT, if any answer solves your problem please consider  marking it as accepted. If you have a new question you should click **Ask question ** button (top right) and ask a new question this will help others who may face the same problem as you do.